# Add to dictionary and count strings in a file based on specific conditions

Tags: python, string, file, dictionary, count

The program that I'm trying to make is supposed to take a file (dummy file for example, stream.txt):

```
andrew I hate mondays.
fred Python is cool.
fred Ko Ko Bop Ko Ko Bop Ko Ko Bop for ever
andrew @fred no it isn't, what do you think @john???
judy @fred enough with the k-pop
judy RT @fred Python is cool.
andrew RT @judy @fred enough with the k pop
george RT @fred Python is cool.
andrew DM @john Oops
john DM @andrew Who are you go away! Do you know him, @judy?
```

and print the top *n* users with the most retweeted tweets. The first word in a given line is the user and everything else is the contents of a message, where 'RT' indicates a retweet, and 'DM' indicates a direct message.

The program should print the user with the most retweets (**not the user that retweets the most**) next to the number of retweets that user has accumulated.

n should be based on the number of users, which means if there is a tie there will be less than n lines printed as there will be two users with the same number value. The solution for the dummy data above would be as follows:

```
Enter n: 10
2 fred
1 judy
```

The code that I currently have is:

```
#define libraries used, counter, dictionary, and file path
from collections import Counter, defaultdict
from pathlib import Path

def main():
    #define n as user input, can only be an integer
    n = input('Enter n: ')
    try:
        n = int(n)
    except:
        print('Invalid input.')
        return
    #Open file from path, read line by line and remove whitespace characters
    ss = Path('stream.txt').read_text().strip().split('\n')
    #Count tweets and add to dictionary, strip spaces and tabs, separate tweets from retweets
    c = Counter([
        i.strip().split(' ', 1)[0] for i in ss
        if i.strip().split(' ', 2)[1] in ('RT @ ')

    ])
    d = defaultdict(list)
    #Formatting
    for k, v in c.most_common():
        d[v].append(k)
    print('\n'.join([f'{k} {" ".join(v)}' for k, v in list(d.items())[:n]]))

#runs main
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

However this gives an output of:

```
Enter n: 10
1 judy andrew george
```

I'm new to python and have no idea how to progress from this point. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os

# Return tweeted user if a tweet is a retweet
def get_tweeted_user(tweet):
    index = tweet.find(" RT ")
    if index < 0:
        return None
    contents = tweet.split(' ')
    if len(contents) < 2 or contents[1] != "RT" or contents[2][0] != '@':
        return None
    return contents[2][1:]

# Return top users, a list like [(2,'fred'), (1,judy)]
def top_users(file_path="stream.txt", n=2):
    users_map = {}
    if not os.path.exists(file_path):
        return None
    with open(file_path, 'r') as lines:
        for line in lines:
            user = get_tweeted_user(line)
            if user:
                # Update users_map
                if users_map.has_key(user):
                    users_map[user] += 1
                else:
                    users_map[user] = 1
    # Sort users_map using tweeted times
    users = sorted(users_map.items(), key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True)

    # Return top n users
    return users[:n]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    tus = top_users()
    print tus
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I get this error message with the code:   print tus
            ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(tus)?

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: My python version is 2.7.6, it works well. Python API may be different from the version you currently use. Maybe you can read official python docs to use correct API replace the codes, then it will work.

Comment: Use "if user in users_map" to replace "users_map.has_key(user)", and use "print(tus)" to replace "print tus".

Comment: rather than the [('user1', 93), ('user2', 91)] format
**Edit** any way to format like example output in second grey box?

Comment: Formatting the result is very simple. for u in tus: print("%d %s" % (u[1], u[0]))

Answer (score 0):

Debugged version of your code:

```
from collections import Counter, defaultdict
from pathlib import Path

def main():
    #define n as user input, can only be an integer
    n = input('Enter n: ')
    try:
        n = int(n)
    except:
        print('Invalid input.')
        return
    #Open file from path, read line by line and remove whitespace characters
    ss = Path('stream.txt').read_text().strip().split('\n')
    #Count tweets and add to dictionary, strip spaces and tabs, separate tweets from retweets
    c = Counter([
        i.strip().split(' ', 3)[2][1:] for i in ss
        if i.strip().split(' ', 2)[1] in ('RT @ ')

    ])
    d = defaultdict(list)
    #Formatting
    for k, v in c.most_common():
        d[v].append(k)
    counts = list(d.keys())
    persons = list(d.values())
    print_str = '\n'.join(["%d %s" %(counts[i],' '.join(persons[i])) for i in range(len(counts))])
    print(print_str)

#runs main
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**NOTE:** You were printing the user that retweets the most instead of printing the user with the most retweets.

Just needed to edit this line:

```
c = Counter([
    i.strip().split(' ', 3)[2][1:] for i in ss
    if i.strip().split(' ', 2)[1] in ('RT @ ')
```